# Designer 2010: URL Link to Name in Email Not Displaying Latest List Update

Tags: 2010

I need help with a Designer workflow problem.

I have two lists in a single site.  When updating an item on LIST 1 the workflow updates certain fields on LIST 2.  It copies NAME1 field from LIST 1 and updates NAME2 in List 2.  The NAME1 field gets modified from time to time and updates NAME2.

Following this workflow step an email is auto generated with hyperlinks in the body to NAME1 and NAME2 (using Add or Change Lookup).  Although the links bring up the correct item in a form, the NAME2 link in the email always shows the previous name it was given.  Once the update takes place from LIST 1, and I then refresh the LIST 2 screen, the name changes to match LIST 1.

It seems like the workflow is processing before the LIST 2 is fully updated.  How can I make the workflow refresh LIST 2 (if there is such a thing) before it grabs NAME2 for the email?  Thank you.

Comment: Can't you use List1.Name field inside the email body?

Comment: Yes, and I do, which doesn’t' make sense.   It doesn’t pick up the new updated name but takes the previous name which I can see in the list before I refresh the screen.  After refresh, it shows the new updated name, the one I want to display in the email link.